# Digital Signature in PowerShell v2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How can i create digital signature using PowerShell, is there any build-in commands for that?
It should be same to the open SSL command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but check out [Code Signing with OpenSSL and PowerShell](http://huddledmasses.org/code-signing-with-openssl-and-powershell/) for their New-CodeSigningCert script.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on what you want to sign.

If you want to sign a PowerShell Script then you can use Set-AuthenticodeSignature cmdlets to sign the script. You DO need a code signing certificate to use this cmdlets.